# Wordpress update button works but not publish button

Tags: wordpress

I asked the programmer to have the title of every post automatically be the date selected and the place selected (to allow users to save some time). When I click 'publish' the title of the post is the date twice (ie; 03-26-15 03-26-15). Then the 'publish' button turns into an 'update' button. And then when I click 'update' the title will be correct (ie; 03-26-15 London). I'm trying to figure out how to get it this way after clicking 'publish' the first time. The programmer disappeared and I can't figure it out. Any help would be great.

```
function post_updated( $post_id ) {

    global $post_type;
    if ($post_type == 'place') {
        if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && !(defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE) ) {
            $postTitle.=get_the_date( 'm/d/Y', $post_id );
            $postTitle.=" ".get_the_title(get_post_meta($post_id, 'place_locale', true) ) ;

            $post['ID'] = $post_id;
            $post['post_title'] =  $postTitle;

            remove_action( 'save_post', 'post_updated' );
            wp_update_post($post);
            add_action( 'save_post', 'post_updated' );
        }
    }

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'post_updated' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.=` operator appends, therefor your titles are being duplicated.
Simply change it to `=` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thx - but I tried removing both .= and just one but neither worked. Maybe I did it wrong tho...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the only function? It seems to only have "update post" code.

Post creation is handled with `wp_insert_post` something like:

```
$my_post = array(
'post_title'    => $title,
'post_content'  => "",
'post_status'   => "pending",
'post_author'   => wp_get_current_user()->ID
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but this may help who got into this question:
There are some problems with the code:

1. `global $post_type` is not defined.
2. As mentioned by @dojs, you should use `=` operator instead of `.=` to define the variable first.
3. `get_the_title()` function only accepts post_id or post object as the param.
4. Since you're dealing with a custom post type of `place`, it's better to use a [post type specific hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/) instead of the general and crowded `save_post` hook.

After these modifications, the final code could be something like this:

```
function tst_post_updated( $post_id )
{
    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && !(defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE) ) {

        $post_title = get_the_date( 'm/d/Y', $post_id );
        $post_title .= " " . get_post_meta($post_id, 'place_locale', true);
        $post_title = sanitize_title($post_title);

        $post['ID'] = $post_id;
        $post['post_title'] =  $post_title;

        remove_action( 'save_post_place', 'tst_post_updated' );
        wp_update_post($post);
        add_action( 'save_post_place', 'tst_post_updated' );
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post_place', 'tst_post_updated' );
```